# How to hide deafult scope value for ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular controller I have this

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.getTotal= function() {
    return 10*Number($scope.o)+
          10*Number($scope.p)+
          10*Number($scope.q)+
          10*Number($scope.r)+
          10*Number($scope.s)+
          10*Number($scope.t);
          $scope.o=0;

    }
         $scope.p=0;
      $scope.q=0;
      $scope.r=0;
      $scope.s=0;
      $scope.t=0;
        });

    <td><input type=" number" class="hobbit"  style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-model="t"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" value="{{getTotal()}}" > </td>
 <td><input type="number" class="form-control" value="{{getTotal()}}" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ></td>
```

The problem is the value in my input box i showing zero ,I want to hide that value any idea how to do that?

Comment: explain it properly, why do you need `$scope.t=0;` in your controller then?

Comment: Am i right you want to see empty if t value is 0 and value if it is not zero?

Comment: Easy! Do this: `style="width:60px;margin:6px; display: none"` :) If it's still not enough, you can add this rule in CSS `body {display: none}`. This should hide this bad boy.

Comment: I need it coz ,I want to add the values of few text boxes which infact gives me Nan if its is not initiallized to zero

Comment: Add example what exactly do you need

Comment: @triptitiwari it's because _some number_ + _undefined_ = NaN. You can try adding `($scope.t || 0)` instead, which will remove the possibility of `t` having falsy values like null or undefined

Comment: where i have to add it?? @Aleksey

Comment: @triptitiwari where you "add the values of few text boxes". Once again here is an example: `5 + undefined == NaN`, `5 + (undefined || 0) == 5`, so you can use `some_values + ($scope.t || 0)` to guarantee that `t` will ether be 0 or your typed number

Comment: in your example it can be `... + 10*(Number($scope.t) || 0)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to display the default value, maybe you can for example **not** set the default value. All this part of code can be removed:

```
$scope.p=0;
$scope.q=0;
$scope.r=0;
$scope.s=0;
$scope.t=0;
```

And once you're sending your form, if you detect that your variable is still undefined, then set it with your default value.

```
$scope.getTotal= function() {
    if($scope.p === undefined)
        $scope.p = 0;
    if($scope.q === undefined)
        $scope.q = 0;
    if($scope.r === undefined)
        $scope.r = 0;
    if($scope.s === undefined)
        $scope.s = 0;
    if($scope.t === undefined)
        $scope.t = 0;

    return 10*Number($scope.o)+
        10*Number($scope.p)+
        10*Number($scope.q)+
        10*Number($scope.r)+
        10*Number($scope.s)+
        10*Number($scope.t);
        $scope.o=0;
}
```